# In how many ways can 4 boys and 4 girls be seated on 8 chairs in a row so that every boy sits next to at least one girl?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

> In how many ways can 4 boys and 4 girls be seated on 8 chairs in a row so that every boy sits next to at least one girl?

My attempt: From the $4$ boys and the $4$ girls, select one boy and one girl each and $.2!$.  As there are $2$ such cases, make a series and multiply
$(4~1).(4~1).(8~2).2!$. Select any $2$ chairs from the $8$ and continue doing this.
$2^4(4~1)^2.(3~1)^2.(2~1)^2(1~1)^2.(8~2).(6~2)(4~2)(2~2)(1~1)$

Is this the correct solution? (N r)represents n chose r

Comment: What does your notation $(a~b)$ mean?  If you are trying to write $\binom{n}{k}$, you should type `$\binom{n}{k}$`.  This [MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: Oh thnk brother i was having problems typing im new here

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to do this is to use the fact that when you multiply polynomials in $x$, the coefficients of the polynomials get added up.

So if we let $x^0,x^1,x^2$ represent that $0,1,2$ boys can occupy spaces between girls, the vacancies for boys are

$\boxed{1}G\boxed{2}G\boxed{2}G\boxed{2}G\boxed{1}$, which we can represent as

$(x^0+x^1)(x^0+x^1+x^2)(x^0+x^1+x^2)(x^0+x^1+x^2)(x^0+x) = (1+x)^2(1+x+x^2)^3$

Multiplying it our gives the coefficient of $x^4 = 26$

Now all we need to do is to multiply by $4!$ each for girls/boys to  decide who sits where

thus final answer = $26*4!4! = \boxed{14976}$

---

**PS**

I have tried to take the fear out of what are known as *ordinary generating functions*. However, if you want to solve it in a conventional way, I am giving an outline of the approach you can use by breaking up into cases

- Two double seats  used, which can be done in $\binom32$ ways, no mores seats to be filled
- One double seat used, other seats only single occupancy, which can be done in $\binom31\binom42$ ways [Choose double seat to be filled]$\times$[Seat remaining boys in the $4$ seats now to be used as "singles"]
- Proceed thus (be careful, other cases may be trickier!) and after adding up all the cases, multiply by $4!4!$

**PPS**

You would do well to look at the answers [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2559824/in-how-many-ways-can-3-boys-and-3-girls-be-seated-in-a-row-such-that-each-bo?rq=1) with a number of approaches to a problem on a smaller scale where I have used a different approach, and an approach using inclusion-exclusion (with which you may be more familiar) has been provided by N. F. Taussig

Comment: In your second bullet point, after the only double seat has been filled, there are four single seats in which the remaining two boys can be placed.  You could also provide a link to your solution to [In how many ways can $3$ boys and $3$ girls be seated in a rows such that reach boy is adjacent to at least one girl?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2559824/in-how-many-ways-can-3-boys-and-3-girls-be-seated-in-a-row-such-that-each-bo?rq=1).

Comment: @N.F.Taussig: Thanks, I have added a PPS along the lines suggested by you. I was searching for such previous questions but didn't find; must remember to search under the question links first !

Answer (score -3):

Boys can occupy seats 1,3,5,7 and girls can occupy seats 2,4,6,8.
Each group of boys, as well as each group of girls can arrange themselves in 4! ways. Additionally, boys and girls can exchange seating arrangements. Thus, overall seating arrangements (**permutations**) for 8 boys and girls = 2*(4!)*(4!) = **1,152**.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Bro i your sopution the case in which gbbgbgb cases like these ehre there are 2 boys in between are missing right?

Comment: Your solution is incorrect since it is possible for two boys to sit in adjacent seats if those two boys sit between two girls.